# Orphaned Availability Group Name

Tags: sql-server, distributed-availability-groups

So I was creating a distributed availability group and noticed I wanted to change the name of the AG so I tried to run DROP AVAILABILITY GROUP.  But it was already seeding and was just stuck in "Cancelling" status. So I restarted the SQL Service to get it to quit trying to seed.  But now the AG is gone on the primary but is still in the sys.availability_groups table as a record, so when I try to recreate it, it says that it already exists.

Is anyone aware of how to fix that without having to create a ticket with Microsoft since Adhoc updates aren't allowed on system tables anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I ran the DROP AVAILABILITY GROUP on the local AG name and it cleaned up the orphaned distributed availability group row in the sys.availability_groups table.